# how to get (and set) variables inside a ruby class?

Tags: ruby, class

I update this question to better reflect what I have problems to grasp.  The example below kind of work but how can I access the Sub class then I have defined it inside the Base class? Should it not be better to do the call outside the class? If so how do I do that?  The second question I have in this example is how to grab values so I can use them in another class. Here I store the values in an array that I later need to unpack in another class. Should I not be able to use a proc for this?

Basically what I want to do is to sort the methods into two different classes depending on if they are nested or not.

```
class Sub 

  def initialize(base_class_method)
     @base_class_method = base_class_method
     @sub_methods = []
  end

   # omitted code here

  def base_class_method
     @base_class_method
  end

  def sub_actions(method)
     @sub_methods << method
  end

  def return_sub_methods
    @sub_methods
  end

  def method_missing(sub_method, &block)
    if sub_method
      sub_method
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

class Base

  def initialize
    @base_methods = []
  end

  # omitted code here

  def base_actions(method)
    @base_methods << method
  end

  def return_base_methods
    @base_methods
  end

  def method_missing(method, &block)
    if block_given?
      Sub.new(method).instance_eval(&block)
    elsif method
    base_actions(method)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end


base = Base.new
base.instance_eval do
  something1
  something_with_a_block do
    something_inside_block1_1
    something_inside_block1_2
  end
  something2
  something_with_a_block2_2 do
  something_inside_block2_1
  end
end

p base.return_base_methods   #=> [:something1, :something2]   works!
```

Comment: not sure what you want it to do. But right now gets method just returns what you pass in...

Comment: what I don't get is how to access z in this example (outside the class.  z.get ?)

Comment: there's no instance variables to return. All your get does is return what you pass in -- useless.

Comment: please improve your question.

Comment: sorry, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```rb
class Test
  # reserved method to instantiate object
  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end

  # getters
  def a
    @a
  end

  def b
    @b
  end

  def c
    @c
  end

  def abc
    [@a, @b, @c] # returns an array
  end

  # setters
  def a=(var)
    @a = var
  end

  def b=(var)
    @b = var
  end

  def c=(var)
    @c = var
  end

  # set values all at once
  def update(a, b, c)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end
end

z = Test.new('something','something','something')
z.update('something!','nothing!',"a thing!")
z.a
z.b
z.c
z.a = 'wow, new value!'
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can shorten getters and setters using `attr_accessor`, but I thought it would be better where those getters and setters come from. Definately check out `attr_accessor` though. It's used in Rails all the time.

Comment: I did edit the example, the exact hash is unknown. sorry my bad!

Comment: @garbagecollection you should edit your answer with info about using attr_accessor in place of creating manual getters and setters, instead of relegating it to an aside in a comment.

Comment: I have updated this question after @garbagecollection provided this answer. It was a bad formulated question and he answer reflect what you could make out of that question